# Can the WSO2 ESB JMS transport add custom JMS headers

Tags: jms, wso2, apache-axis, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I am trying to add some custom JMS headers, required by another 3rd party system to the outgoing message.

I have tried adding the following property mediator:

```
<property xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="HEADER" value="VALUE" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
```

The JMS broker (ActiveMQ) is receiving the HEADER:VALUE but treating it as a property, rather than a header

I know there are reserved JMS header keywords, such as `JMS_TIME_TO_LIVE`, however these aren't well documented.

I suspect I may have to add something to the `TRANSPORT_HEADERS` map, however the documentation states it is filled from the client request, and again, these show as properties in ActiveMQ rather than headers

Comment: Can you try scope="axis2"?

Comment: I have tried changing the scope to Axis2, but it then doesnt send the data as message properties to ActiveMQ.

I have looked through the Axis2 JMS transport code in the WSO2 repository, and it doesnt appear that there is a facility to add custom headers.  Hopefully this would be added in future versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original was working correctly, and adding the values to the User defined properties collection of the JMS message.  This is the correct place to add application headers.

`<property xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="HEADER" value="VALUE" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>`

The issue was a configuration error in the 3rd party tool.